# Active.workbooks not working on Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I'm providing a number of excel files in a folder to people. People open 'Start Here', click a macro button, and it auto generates some files.

The whole thing works well when the folder and files are on computer 1. When I use them on my other computer, I get an error on the first line.

Computer 1 - Windows 10 & Office 365
Computer 2 - Windows 10 & Office 2010

Can anyone tell me why? Is there any code that I can include at the beginning (i.e. including reference libraries) that could help make the file more suitable on different systems?

Error on code line:

```
WS_Count = Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").Worksheets.Count
```

run-time error 9; subscript out of range

Note, when I change this to Activeworkbook.Worksheets.Count it works, but I'd rather not do that as I need to reference different workbooks as I progress. As it works on one computer and another, it doesn't seem to b a typo.....

Full code:

```
Sub GenerateAssessments()
    Dim currentdirectory As String
    Dim CXsourcefile As String
    Dim BACsourcefile As String

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim ws As Integer
    Dim ws2 As Integer
    Dim ws3 As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    Dim Country As String
    Dim CXnewname As String
    Dim BACnewname As String

    Dim BACWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim CXWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim xlobj As Object

    Dim CountBrandsIncluded As Integer 'CountBrandsIncluded contains the number of brands, 'adding eleven to give the row of the last brand to  'included in the range Brand TOData
    Dim EndRowBrandsIncluded As Integer

    Dim CountBrandsNotIncluded As Integer
    Dim StartRowBrandsNotIncluded As Integer
    Dim EndRowBrandsNotIncluded As Integer

    Dim StartColumnBrandsNotNeededBACTab As Integer
    Dim StartColumnBrandsNotNeededQsTabs As Integer

    Dim BrandTODataIncluded As Variant
    Dim BrandTODataNotIncluded As Variant
    Dim TotalBrandTOStated As Currency

    Dim ErrorInpute As Variant
    Dim wsprotect As Worksheet
    Dim pwd As String



    currentdirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Find driectory of current workbook
    CXsourcefile = currentdirectory & "\" & "CXSource.xlsx" 'set CX source destination and file
    BACsourcefile = currentdirectory & "\" & "BACSource.xlsx"


    WS_Count = Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").Worksheets.Count
    'Find number of worksheets in active workbook

    'activate code for each sheet by looping
    For I = 1 To WS_Count ' Begin the loop.
        If Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").Worksheets(I).Visible = True Then 'Run the loop on visible sheets only
            Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").Worksheets(I).Activate ' Set the worksheet as active
            'Insert your code here to execute on each sheet.

            'Country specific names and directories
            Country = Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").ActiveSheet.Range("S2") 'get country and active sheet and create copies of the BAC and CX files
            CXnewname = currentdirectory & "\" & Country & " Consumer Experience Benchmark - protected with red metrics.xlsx" 'set country specific name for new CX file
            BACnewname = currentdirectory & "\" & Country & " Business Adoption Continuum Benchmark - protected with red metrics.xlsx" 'set country specific name for new BAC file

            'no. of brands and row referncing for country tab
            'included brands
            CountBrandsIncluded = Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").ActiveSheet.Range("P10") 'get no. brands included
            EndRowBrandsIncluded = 11 + CountBrandsIncluded 'Brands start at S12 'set last row of brands to be included

            'excluded brands' rows
            CountBrandsNotIncluded = Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").ActiveSheet.Range("P12") 'get no. brands excluded
            StartRowBrandsNotIncluded = 11 + CountBrandsIncluded + 1
            EndRowBrandsNotIncluded = 11 + CountBrandsIncluded + CountBrandsNotIncluded

            'unneeded brand columns in BAC and Qs tabs
            StartColumnBrandsNotNeededBACTab = 4 + CountBrandsIncluded + 1
            StartColumnBrandsNotNeededQsTabs = 7 + CountBrandsIncluded + 1
            StartColumnBrandsNotNeededDigitalCXTab = 6 + CountBrandsIncluded + 1

            'copy total brand TO Data
            TotalBrandTOStated = Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").ActiveSheet.Range("T4:T4").Value
            'copy brand data to be included
            BrandTODataIncluded = Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").ActiveSheet.Range("S12:T" & EndRowBrandsIncluded).Value
            'copy data not being included
            BrandTODataNotIncluded = Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").ActiveSheet.Range("S" & StartRowBrandsNotIncluded & ":T" & EndRowBrandsNotIncluded).Value

            'Create country BAC and CX Files
            Set xlobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'Copy File Script : object.copyfile,source,destination,file overright(True is default)
                xlobj.CopyFile CXsourcefile, CXnewname, False 'Copy CX file
            Set xlobj = Nothing
1
            Set xlobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                xlobj.CopyFile BACsourcefile, BACnewname, False
            Set xlobj = Nothing

            'Open and edit country's BAC file
            Set BACWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(BACnewname) 'open new country's BAC file

                BACWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("T4:T4").Value = TotalBrandTOStated
                BACWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("S3:S3").Value = Country
                BACWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("S12:T" & EndRowBrandsIncluded).Value = BrandTODataIncluded
                BACWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("S" & StartRowBrandsNotIncluded & ":" & "U51").Delete Shift:=xlUp
                BACWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("S" & StartRowBrandsNotIncluded & ":T" & EndRowBrandsNotIncluded).Value = BrandTODataNotIncluded

                BACWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated BAC").Select
                BACWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated BAC").Range(Cells(1, StartColumnBrandsNotNeededBACTab), Cells(1, 44)).EntireColumn.Delete

                ws = 4
                For ws = 4 To 8
                BACWorkbook.Sheets(ws).Select
                BACWorkbook.Sheets(ws).Range(Cells(1, StartColumnBrandsNotNeededQsTabs), Cells(1, 47)).EntireColumn.Delete
                Next

                'hide all except Qs tabs
                For ws4 = 1 To 3
                BACWorkbook.Sheets(ws4).Select
                BACWorkbook.Sheets(ws4).Visible = xlSheetHidden
                Next ws4

                'password protect the sheets and workbook
                pwd = "Digital2" ' Put your password here
                For Each ws4 In Worksheets
                    ws4.Protect Password:=pwd
                Next

                BACWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=False, Password:=pwd

                'save and close
                BACWorkbook.Save
                BACWorkbook.Close

            Set CXWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(CXnewname)

                CXWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("T4:T4").Value = TotalBrandTOStated
                CXWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("S3:S3").Value = Country
                CXWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("S12:T" & EndRowBrandsIncluded).Value = BrandTODataIncluded
                CXWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("S" & StartRowBrandsNotIncluded & ":" & "U51").Delete Shift:=xlUp
                CXWorkbook.Sheets("Brand + TO Data Inputs").Range("S" & StartRowBrandsNotIncluded & ":T" & EndRowBrandsNotIncluded).Value = BrandTODataNotIncluded



                CXWorkbook.Sheets("Digital CX Brand Baselines").Select
                CXWorkbook.Sheets("Digital CX Brand Baselines").Range(Cells(1, StartColumnBrandsNotNeededDigitalCXTab), Cells(1, 46)).EntireColumn.Delete

                'rename the brand tabs
                Z = 5 + CountBrandsIncluded

                For y = 6 To Z
                    On Error GoTo errorbox
                        CXWorkbook.Sheets(y).Activate
                        ActiveSheet.Name = Range("K3").Value
Continue1:
                Next y

                'delete extra brand tabs
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws2 = 5 + CountBrandsIncluded
                ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
                Do Until ws2 = ws3
                    Sheets(ws3).Select
                    CXWorkbook.Sheets(ws3).Delete
                    ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
                Loop

                Application.DisplayAlerts = True

                'hide all except Qs tabs
                For ws4 = 1 To 4
                CXWorkbook.Sheets(ws4).Select
                CXWorkbook.Sheets(ws4).Visible = xlSheetHidden
                Next ws4

                For ws4 = 6 To ws3
                CXWorkbook.Sheets(ws4).Select
                CXWorkbook.Sheets(ws4).Visible = xlSheetHidden
                Next ws4

                'password protect the sheets and workbook
                pwd = "Digital2" ' Put your password here
                For Each ws4 In Worksheets
                    ws4.Protect Password:=pwd
                Next

                CXWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=False, Password:=pwd

                'save and close
                CXWorkbook.Save
                CXWorkbook.Close
        End If

    Next I
    Exit Sub


errorbox:
ErrorInput = InputBox("The brand name is not a valid Excel tab name. Please enter another.")
ActiveSheet.Name = ErrorInput
Resume Continue1
End Sub
```

Comment: Your workbook reference fails because the computer has the Windows Explorer "hide extensions for know filetypes" option unchecked.  The full workbook file name (including extension) will *always* work, regardless of that setting, so use that.

Comment: Do you need to add the extension on to the workbook path also, `mybook.xlsx` for example?

Comment: On this line: `WS_Count = Application.Workbooks("Start Here - Brand and TO Data Input").Worksheets.Count**` are the two asterisks `*` a typo or copy/paste error?

Comment: @FreeMan It was probably OP trying to mark it as the error line for us

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams - that's worked!

Comment: @FreeMan - yeah, I was trying to use bold formatting. I've removed now.